# Combine multiple column into 1 column on the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

I have an example table like this :

```
  id |  Name   | code1 | code2
   ------------------------------
  1  |  John   |  001  |  AC2
  2  |  Anna   |  002  |  AH5
  3  |  Brad   |  003  |  BB1
```

I want to combine column code1 and code2 (and another column if any) into 1 column and duplicated data on another column in the table so it will have a result like this :

```
  id |  Name   | code 
   -------------------
  1  |  John   |  001  
  1  |  John   |  AC2  
  2  |  Anna   |  002  
  2  |  Anna   |  AH5  
  3  |  Brad   |  003  
  3  |  Brad   |  BB1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `UNION` or `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT
    id,
    Name,
    code1 As code
FROM
    YourTable

UNION

SELECT
    id,
    Name,
    code2 As code
FROM
    YourTable

ORDER BY
    id,
    Name,
    code
```

[UNION (Transact-SQL) - SQL Server | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

**NB:** As per Aaron's comment below, `UNION` will remove duplicate rows, whereas `UNION ALL` will include them. If you have the same value in `code1` and `code2` on a single source row, `UNION` will produce a single output row, whereas `UNION ALL` will produce two identical output rows. It's not clear from your question which behaviour you would want.

Comment: I would recommend UNION ALL. Unfortunately UNION DISTINCT is the default behavior with or without the explicit keyword, and usually unnecessary.

Comment: @AaronBertrand It's not clear from the data whether the OP wants two identical rows if `code1` and `code2` contain the same value.

Comment: I feel like logically it's far more likely they want both rows, especially given the sample formats are unlikely to collide anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with only **a single scan** of the source table. Simply unpivot using `CROSS APPLY (VALUES`

```sql
SELECT
  t.id,
  t.Name,
  v.code
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
    (code1),
    (code2)
) v(code)
```